# Load data only once in view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, video

I've been stuck with something for a while now and have not been able to find a solution for it.

I am building an app that is similar to musical.ly where there is a custom navigation controller on the homepage allowing user to swipe across 3 screens with a tab bar at the bottom (see app screenshots).

Now what's happening here is, that just as I swipe from 1 screen to another, and then come back again, it loads all of the data again and takes me back to the first video - I want to be able to swipe between screens and come back at the same video at the same timestamp in the video that I was on earlier.

```
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:pageViewController.view animated:TRUE];
    [self loadjson_homeVideoData];
});
```

Above is my code block in which i’m calling a web service, storing response in NSArray and passing this array to NSDictionary to another view controller. (NSArray and Dictionary both are strong property)

the problem is, when i move to another controller and come to home controller all data becomes null and app crashes.

Is there a way to display that data when that view controller called again ? I just want to load data at once and not every time.

PS: Calling dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{ in ViewDidLoad()

I would really appreciate some guidance here - for reference you may check the musical.ly app on iOS

[this is the home screen, see at the top are three screens that the user can swipe among](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ws0Ow.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:pageViewController.view animated:TRUE];
    [self loadjson_homeVideoData];
});
```

Replace your code with this and then run and check.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:pageViewController.view animated:TRUE];
        [self loadjson_homeVideoData];
    });
```

Comment: In your example: You adding HUD to your view and loading json in global queue. You should use main queue for the HUD, instead of global queue for both.

Comment: The problem isn't really about calling the api in queue. I am storing the response in NSDictionary of the home view controller, and when I move to an other controller, the dictionary becomes null and the data doesn't stick.

Comment: are you passing that dictionary to nextViewController?